# Type casting objects without pointers

Tags: c++

I'd like to type cast from a base class to a derived class. For example:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {}
A a;
// do stuff with a
B b = (B)a;
```

This works fine with `B* b = (B*)&a;` but I'm trying to avoid that. Is this possible?

Comment: In C++, that usually leads to slicing, and puts you on the fast track to pain town.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel sometimes slicing is the correct operation

Comment: "*This works fine with `B* b = (B*)&a;`*" No, it does not. It will compile, but any attempt to *use* the pointer after that cast is undefined behavior, because `&a` does *not* point to an object of type `B`.

Comment: All Bs are As, but not all As are Bs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Jedi mind trick* This is the answer you are looking for. */Jedi mind trick*

`B b = *(B*)&a;`

It's the same concept as getting the value of an unsigned char (byte) array at a specific offset (e.g. `int foo = *(int*)&bar[0xC];`) but with objects.

```
#include <stdio.h>


class A
{
public:
    bool m_bIsB;

public:
    A() { this->m_bIsB = false; }

public:
    virtual bool IsB() const { return this->m_bIsB; }
};
class B : public A
{
    //virtual bool IsB() const { return true; }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    printf("IsB ? %s\n", a.IsB() ? "true" : "false");
    a.m_bIsB = true;
    printf("IsB ? %s\n", a.IsB() ? "true" : "false");
    B b = *(B*)&a;
    printf("IsB ? %s\n", b.m_bIsB ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}


IsB ? false
IsB ? true
IsB ? true
```

If you want to understand why this works, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8u_k2LIZyo (you can skip to **1st Step: Evil Bit Hack**)

Comment: this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the left side of the initialization:

```
B b =
```

No matter what you put after the equal sign, `B b` declares a new `B`. It will call the constructor with whatever you put after. So this is a new object, distinct from all other previous objects.

So you want to be able to create new `B`s using an instance of `A`? Just add the required constructor:

```
class B : public A {
    explicit B(A const& a) : A{a} {}
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
B b = B(a);
```

Comment: What about doing `B* b = static_cast<B*>(a);` ? What would be the difference with that and doing an upcast?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I'm not sure what you mean. `a` is an `A` and you want to cast it to a pointer to `B`?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 is far as I know you cannot convert an object to a pointer using casts.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Think of what can happen if you tell the compiler that the A you're holding is really a B and then force the program to use the A is if it were a B. A almost certainly does not have all of the functionality of B, so what will happen if you invoke a method that doesn't exist In A on an A? The answer to that is [good question!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not.

Let's assume that the derived class B has its own data member `bar_`:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {
  int bar_;
}
```

What value do you suppose `b.bar_` to have if `B b = (B)a;` works?

Also, even if `B* b = (B*)&a;` has no compiling error, it is dangers since the initial value of `b->bar_` will be undefined.

By the way, `A a = b;` does work fine because of object slicing.

Comment: *"By the way, `A a = b;` does work fine because of object slicing."* ??? You seem to have cause and effect confused. That line causes slicing; it is not an effect of slicing. That line works because a derived class can be implicitly converted to an unambiguous base, resulting in the copy constructor of `A` being invoked. The *result* (not the cause) is that the parts of `b` that are not part of the `A` base are lost, a.k.a. "slicing".